# How can I hide letter counter from bottom of TextField in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

[image]

I'm facing a small problem. As you can see, i have set maxLength 1 of TextField in Flutter, But i'm unable to hide bottom label of text counter.

Answer (score 368):

To hide counter value from **TextField** or **TextFormField** widget while using `maxLength` attribute, try following:

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: "Email",
    counterText: "",
  ),
  maxLength: 40,
),
```

In this, I have set `counterText` attribute inside `InputDecoration` property with empty value. Hope it will help.

Comment: This is great if you just want to hide it, but it's still there and take up space often resulting in an uneven text box.
Replacing maxLength with `TextField(
            inputFormatters: [LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(mMaxLength)]
)`
Will solve it, but requires you to add an extra library to the file.

Comment: this is working but `counterText` taking space height and affecting the UI

Comment: for me doesn't keep the empty space, its being removed, running latest version of flutter helps?

Comment: @FarhanaNaazAnsari also set your helperText = '  ' . if it doesn't work wrap it with container

Answer (score 171):

This is the proper approach, it will prevent extra space below the Text Field, and also avoid extra code to set a null widget.

You can use input formatters in `TextField`

The following is:

```
    inputFormatters:[
      LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(1),
    ]
```

Thank You!

Comment: It works, but requires you to import an extra library to the file: `import 'package:flutter/services.dart';`

Comment: I used this method with `InputDecoration.collapsed`, but It's not working. However, user10481267's answer works.

Comment: It might be obvious, but `maxLength` parameter must be removed for this to work properly.

Answer (score 52):

you can use InputDecoratoin to hide letter counter.

```
TextFormField(
   decoration: InputDecoration(
     labelText: "username",
     counterStyle: TextStyle(height: double.minPositive,),
     counterText: ""
)
```

Comment: Question is related to TextField, not TextFormField. Thanks for your suggestion in case of TextFormField.

Comment: answer is TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(counterText: '',))

Comment: You just saved my ass. Long life for you, friend.

Answer (score 44):

You can hide the counter by adding `counterText: ''`, inside the **textfield** decoration. It will simply display an empty String.

Comment: IT still takes the counter space

Answer (score 39):

Simply set counter to Offstage() will do the trick.

```
TextField(
    maxLines: 1,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      counter: Offstage(),
    ),
),
```

Comment: This solution still affects the GUI (displaces the input text above the max length counter). The best solution (atleast for my use-case) was the ``counterText=""`` solution.

Answer (score 24):

You can do:

```
TextField(
   maxLength: 10,
   buildCounter: (BuildContext context, { int currentLength, int maxLength, bool isFocused }) => null,
)
```

Answer (score 18):

Most of the answers seem to work. Another way would be to assign the counter with a shrink SizeBox.

```
TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: "Email",
    counter: SizedBox.shrink()
),
  maxLength: 40,
),
```

Comment: Works for me without having to import any new library!

Comment: Did you add any value for the shrinked size box?

Answer (score 15):

Add ***counterText: "",*** to InputDecoration

[image: Image example of counterText]

```
TextField(
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        counterText: "",
    ),
    maxLength: 10,
),
```

Answer (score 12):

This alone solved my problem!

```
TextField(
   decoration: InputDecoration(
     labelText: "Table Number",
     counterText: ""
)
```

Answer (score 10):

Whenever you don't need something in flutter just put an empty container!

```
TextField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: "Email",
    counter: Container(),
  ),
  maxLength: 20,
),
```

Comment: this also hides validation error message, not good solution if you still need it

Comment: Empty containers aren't recommended for use. Better to use the OffStage widget or a SizedBox.

Answer (score 10):

Simply set buildCounter to null.
It is a callback that generates a custom [InputDecorator.counter] widget

```
TextField(
   maxLength: (some length),
   buildCounter: (BuildContext context, {int currentLength, int maxLength, bool isFocused}) => null,
);
```

Answer (score 10):

For null-safety use this:

```
TextField(
   maxLength: 10,
   buildCounter: (BuildContext context, {int? currentLength, int? maxLength, bool? isFocused}) => null,
)
```

Comment: This is the best answer IMO to remove the counter completely since setting the "counter" parameter in the InputDecoration to OffStage() or other zero space widget may hide the counter, but I have noticed that there is a 4 pixel height padding that remains - so this "buildCounter" method completely removes it.

Comment: I agree. This answer is the most flexible and isn't that too difficult to implement considering the added amount of control you now have.

Comment: Please mark this as an accepted answer. This solution is standard one.

Answer (score 6):

You can use input formatters in TextField setting a limit to input and this is the best approach if you just want to hide the counter making a input limit.

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

inputFormatters:[
      LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(1),
]
```

Or you can customize the  decoration making a counter = Container():

```
 decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: "Email",
    counter: Container(),
  ),
```

You if prefer to customize the buildCounter, here is how to do it properly (you can also customise the font, color etc). When you text field loses the focus the counter limits will disappears. Or you can just set

```
        TextField(
          controller: _clienteTextEditingController,
          maxLength: 50,
          buildCounter: (BuildContext context,
              {int currentLength, int maxLength, bool isFocused}) {
            return isFocused
                ? Text(
                    'The Input Limits are: $currentLength/$maxLength ',
                    style: new TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 10.0,
                    ),
                    semanticsLabel: 'Input constraints',
                  )
                : null;
          },
        ),
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use InputDecoratoin to hide the letter counter.

```
TextField(
            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
            maxLength: 10,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
            **counterText:""**)
           )
```

Comment: I think this one the the best answer

Answer (score 4):

```
    Container(
                    height: 48,
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: CustomColors.kToDark,
                        ),
                        color: CustomColors.White,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8))),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                        cursorColor: CustomColors.kToDark,
                        maxLength: 30,
                        controller: _titleController,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          counterText: "",
                            border: InputBorder.none,
                            isDense: true,
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0))),
                  ),
```

[image]

[image]

Use **counterText: ""** inside InputDecoration()

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to hide the counter widget by using SizedBox:

```
TextFormField(
...
decoration: InputDecoration(
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
    counter: new SizedBox(
      height: 0.0,
    )),
...
)
```

Comment: Good solution but this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51895946/1599713 is better

Answer (score 3):

You can follow the below codes.

```
 TextField(
     controller: myController,
     maxLength: 3,
     buildCounter: (BuildContext context, {int currentLength, int maxLength, bool isFocused}) =>null
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you are still looking for the answer in 2020 here goes:

```
decoration: InputDecoration(                                                       
    counter: Spacer(),                                                             
    labelText: "National ID #",                                                    
    border: InputBorder.none,                                                      
    hintText: 'e.g 01-1234567A12',                                                 
    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey)),
```

In the TextField, use a `Spacer()` as counter... hope this helps, i dont know if it breaks anything else but mine works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Not pretty but works by removing the counter:

```
TextFormField(
  buildCounter: (
    BuildContext context, {
    required int currentLength,
    int? maxLength,
    required bool isFocused,
  }) => null,
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a SizedBox.shrink() for the counter widget in InputDecoration:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a SizedBox with zero height and width:

```
TextField(
          maxLength: 400,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            counter: SizedBox(
              width: 0,
              height: 0,
            ),),)
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @user10481267 in the best answer would be use `buildCounter` property. This gives extreme flexibility and you can even decide dynamically to show the counter or not.

I was building a dynamic form with the required properties in JSON. My implementation is as follows:

```
TextFormField(
    buildCounter: (BuildContext context,
    {
            int currentLength,
            int maxLength,
            bool isFocused}) {
                    if (isFocused)
                            return formFields[index]["max"] == null
                                    ? null
                                    : Text(
                                        '$currentLength / $maxLength',
                                        semanticsLabel: 'character count',
                                      );
                              else
                                return null;
                            },
                            maxLength: formFields[index]["max"] ?? 100,
                            decoration: new InputDecoration(
                              labelText: formFields[index]["hint"] ?? "",
                              fillColor: Colors.green,
                              border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                                borderSide: new BorderSide(),
                              ),
                            )
                          )
```