# Flutter: TextFormField not filling parent Container widget height

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-textformfield

I have an OTP page but the borders made for the input fields does not fill the parent containers.
I made the container color grey and the focused border pink, but it does not fit the height.

[image: OTP Image]

Please what am I missing in my code;

```dart
    Widget _textFieldOTP(BuildContext context, {required bool first, last}) {
    return Container(
      height: 54,
      width: 53,
      color: Colors.grey,
      child: TextFormField(
        autofocus: true,
        onChanged: (value) {
          if(value.length == 1 && last == false){
            FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
          }
          if(value.length == 0 && first == false){
            FocusScope.of(context).previousFocus();
          }
        },
        showCursor: false,
        readOnly: false,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
          textStyle: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            fontSize: 24,
          ),
        ),
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        maxLength: 1,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          counter: Offstage(),
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Color(0x1A484848)),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
          ),
          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Color(0xFFFF2957)),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue raise from counter, also can remove offset.
Include `counterStyle: TextStyle(height: double.minPositive),` and `counterText=""`

```dart
   decoration: InputDecoration(
          counterStyle: TextStyle(height: double.minPositive),
          counterText: "",
          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Color(0x1A484848)),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
          ),
```

```dart
Widget _textFieldOTP(BuildContext context, {required bool first, last}) {
  return Container(
    height: 54,
    width: 53,
    color: Colors.grey,
    child: TextFormField(
      autofocus: true,
      onChanged: (value) {
        if (value.length == 1 && last == false) {
          FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
        }
        if (value.length == 0 && first == false) {
          FocusScope.of(context).previousFocus();
        }
      },
      showCursor: false,
      readOnly: false,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
        textStyle: const TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
          fontSize: 24,
        ),
      ),
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      maxLength: 1,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        counterStyle: TextStyle(height: double.minPositive),
        counterText: "",
        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Color(0x1A484848)),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
        ),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1, color: Color(0xFFFF2957)),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51893926/10157127)