# How to show the counter of the text field outside it in flutter?

Tags: flutter

this is the code for the text field. how to change where I want to show it? it has to be outside the blue border.

would it be possible not to show it and it would stop when 10 characters are filled?

```
Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3),
  child: Container(
    height: size.height * 0.08,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
      color: Colors.white,
      border: Border.all(
        color: Colors.blue,
        width: 2.0, // Adjust the width as needed
      ),
    ),
    child: TextField(
      maxLength: 10,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      decoration: const InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        hintText: "أدخل المبلغ المراد دفعه",
        hintTextDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      ),
      // Use the provided TEXT_FIELD_1 value if needed
      controller: textControllerBill,
    ),
  ),
),
```

text field issue

[image]

Comment: You have to build your own widget to show the counter outside. Use `textControllerBill.text.length` to get the letter count. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51893926/13625293) to hide the internal counter.